# Node.js + socket.io + express framework on Apache Linux Server

Tags: node.js, linux, apache, sockets, real-time

I am new with `node.js` interaction.
But Ι have already installed `node.js` on my server and all necessary `node_modules` on a specific domain of my server.

I built a server `index.js` file , a `index.html` and a `package.json` (all located in `httpdocs`).

**index.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
 io.emit('chat message', "Someone connected");

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
   io.emit('chat message', "Someone has disconnect");
 });

 socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
  console.log('message: ' + msg);
  io.emit('chat message', msg);
   });
 });

http.listen(80, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:80');
});
```

**client script (in index.html)**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
 var socket = io();
 $('form').submit(function(){
   socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
  $('#m').val('');
   return false;
 });
 socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
   $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "App",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "App",
"scripts": {
"start": "node ./index.js"
},
 "dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "latest",
    "express": "latest"
 },
 "author": "developer"
 }
```

When I submit the form the message appears correctly.But `index.js` file does not seem to work at all.

Please let me know what is wrong and how to solve it.

Comment: You have to modify the files, that apache server serves. I don't remember exactly where it is, but you have to exclude index.html from that list (at least). And more common approach is - nginx.